# Adapting Richardson Lucy (RL) Deconvolution for Shot Noise Limited Coherent Imaging

Tags: image-processing, deconvolution, inverse-problem

I am an experimental physicist who is collecting a series of coherent imaging of trapped gas. If you are familiar with phase contrast imaging, you may understand what I mean by coherent imaging. The information about the sample is retrieved as interference between a phase-shifted version illumination and light scattered by the sample. The light I am using is monochromatic. Since the imaging technique is coherent, the point-spread function (PSF) I need to use is $J_1(x)/x$ instead of the usual $(J_1(x)/x)^2$ for a circular aperture. This means that PSF has both **positive and negative** values. (It may be even complex in real-life situations.) I will describe the details of what I actually observe in an image below.

Also, since I am working with a low light-level condition, I thought it is best to use the Richardson-Lucy (RL) algorithm, which seems tailored for deconvolving images with Poisson noise. My understanding of the RL algorithm is based on [Gordon Wetzstein - Stanford EE367/CS448I: Computational Imaging and Display - Lecture 10](http://stanford.edu/class/ee367/slides/lecture10.pdf) (slide numbers 26-30). The algorithm assumes that you have an input $\vec{x}$, which goes through a linear operator $\hat{A}$ (convolution with PSF), and the output is a Poisson random variable $\vec{b}$ with average $\langle\vec{b}\rangle = \hat{A}\vec{x}$.

The assumptions used for the RL algorithm are consistent with typical incoherent imaging, where the PSF and the image are everywhere non-negative, but they are not in general for coherent imaging which may have negative values (because negative values wouldn't make much sense for a Poisson distribution).

**Question**: would there be a way to adopt the RL algorithm for coherent imaging, or more in general, PSF with negative values?

---

More detailed description of a typical image. $I$ denotes intensity. $E$ denotes complex electric field, and $I = |E|^2/2$.

$$
\begin{align*}
I_{\text{image}} &= \frac{|E_{\text{scattered}} + i E_{\text{illumination}}|^2}{2} - I_{\text{illumination}}\\
&= I_{\text{scattered}} + \mathrm{Im}(E_{\text{scattered}} E_{\text{illumination}}^*)\\
E_{\text{illumination}} &= \text{plane wave}\\
E_{\text{scattered}} &\sim\text{spherical wave focused to a spot}\\
|E_{\text{scattered}}| &<< |E_{\text{illumination}}|
\end{align*}
$$
the last condition allows us to ignore $I_{\text{scattered}}$ and focus on the $\mathrm{Im}(E_{\text{scattered}} E_{\text{illumination}}^*)$. Since $E_{\text{illumination}}$ is more-or-less flat, you could say we are imaging a magnified version of $E_{\text{scattered}}$ times its relative phase shift $\phi$ (small) with respect to the illumination.

$$
\begin{align*}
E_{\text{scattered}}  &= E_{\text{illumination}} (e^{i\phi_{gas}}-1)\\
&\approx E_{\text{illumination}}i\phi_{gas}\\
I_{\text{image}}[x,y] &\approx |E_{\text{illumination}}|^2\cdot\phi_{gas}[x,y]
\end{align*}
$$

Here is a sample image that shows fringes.
[image: sample image]

Comment: What about adding large value to the output so all values are non negative, apply the algorithm both to the image and to the added value and then remove it?

Comment: @Royi, I think the problem is that it is unclear what to do with the normalization factor in the RL algorithm. See the term $\mathrm{diag}(A^T\,1)$ in http://bigwww.epfl.ch/deconvolution/challenge2013/index.html?p=doc_math_rl. EDIT: never mind, I think as long as the integral of kernel over all space is positive, it should be okay.